# Не могу установить пакеты для Python (работаю через proxy сервер)

Tags: proxy, pip

Пробую установить пакеты через PIP (в командной строке и VS code)

```
pip install aiogram
```

Выходить ошибка вида

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required'))': /simple/aiogram/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement aiogram (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for aiogram
```

Прописан proxy в файле `pip.ini` в формате `proxy=http://user:pass@proxyserver:8080/`

не помогает(

Comment: А версия питона какая?

Comment: Версия - Python 3.11.4